# App Engine Flexible Environment - Dockerfile Package installs skipped on image build

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

When building a custom runtime in App Engine flexible environment the lines of my Dockerfile in which I am attempting to install packages seem to be being skipped over. Specifically these two:

```
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

RUN sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin
```

The terminal shows that the gcloud app deploy command starts by pulling the python runtime and then skips processing the Dockerfile until this line:

```
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7
```

This is my whole Dockerfile. When the App tries to start it fails as it cannot find the GDAL package installation that I try to install.

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic


RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

RUN sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin


# Create a virtualenv for dependencies. This isolates these packages from
# system-level packages.
# Use -p python3 or -p python3.7 to select python version. Default is version 2.
RUN virtualenv /env -p python3.7



# Setting these environment variables are the same as running
# source /env/bin/activate.
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH

# Copy the application's requirements.txt and run pip to install all
# dependencies into the virtualenv.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Add the application source code.
ADD . /


# Run a WSGI server to serve the application. gunicorn must be declared as
# a dependency in requirements.txt.
CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

Comment: What is in the steps log during the docker build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your `Dockerfile`, Cloud Build shouldn't be pulling the Python runtime but the `ubuntu:bionic` image. Cloud Build will pull the Python runtime when you deploy a non-custom flex app.

I believe you need to set the proper runtime in your app.yaml file, like so:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
...
```

instead of `runtime:python`.

Also, after trying to use your `Dockerfile` for a test, I noticed a couple of issues:

- it seems `add-apt-repository` isn't available by default on the `ubuntu:bionic` image, I had to install it manually.
- You cannot run sudo in Dockerfile

So your Dockerfile would look something like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa

RUN apt-get install -y gdal-bin
...
```